# Is it possible to store a whole webpage in a single binary file and display the site using JS?

Tags: javascript

Assuming I have some images, css and html concatenated in one file. Is it possible to use JS to display the html with images and css properly by ripping up the concatenated binary file somehow?

Comment: Do you need exactly a binary file?

Comment: Sounds like a really really bad way to write a website, even it would be possible somehow.

Comment: It would defeat the purpose of HTTP itself [no cache, no pipelining], but you could have a look at [BSON](http://bsonspec.org/).

Comment: @stijn-geukens: Just being curious.

Comment: ok, curiosity is a virtue :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some ways to pack everything into a single file. But all of them are not crossbrowser. Everything depends on your goals.

Take a look at these formats:

- MHTML http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MHTML
- Webarchive http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webarchive
- Mozilla Archive Format http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Archive_Format

All of them are browser specific and even requires some extensions to be installed.

The easiest and the most supported way is to put all css and js files right into your html file. And use data:uri format to include your images into html.

Theoretically it is even possible to write a binary file reader in javascript.